# Will Heroku's Account Verification charge any value?

Tags: heroku, billing

I have a personal blog hosted in Heroku. I want to buy a custom domain name and point it to my Heroku's app.

Heroku requires a credit card to add custom domains. It's called "Account Verification".

Right now I don't want/can't afford any value from a hosting company. I want to use Heroku completely free.

Will Heroku's Account Verification charge any value?

If my app get too much access, will it scale automatically and charge for it?

Answer (score 7):

Looking at this, with a free account verified you will not be charged if you accidentally exceed the free dyno hours: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

> "When you use all your Free dyno hours for a given month, all Free apps on your account will be forced to sleep for the rest of the month."

Plus you will get a warning when close to reach this quota:

> "When you exceed 80% of your Free dyno quota, you will receive an email notification warning you of your account usage, giving you time to adjust Free dyno usage across your apps."

Answer (score 3):

Verifying your account with Heroku will not charge your anything. If you deploy multiple Heroku apps, and run out of your free hours (1000/month), then your apps will go to sleep for the rest of the month.

If you provision any paid addon services, you will also be charged.

If you are not using the 'free dynos', then you will just be charged normally.

Comment: But will it charge without asking me?

Comment: If you've verified your account: yes.

Comment: Looking at this this doesn't look true : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours "When you use all your Free dyno hours for a given month, all Free apps on your account will be forced to sleep for the rest of the month."

Answer (score 0):

I did verify my account and chose to use only free dynos. As stated by the attached link, after using all free hours, **ALL** apps will be forced to sleep until the renewal.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

Comment: Hi, are you still using Heroku? And does it still imply today? If we are using free dynos, all apps wil be forced to sleep, meaning it will not charge additional fee?

Comment: Hey.. I'm still using it.. that's correct I guess.. they only sleep when not in use